# How to check user availability during registration using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, registration

I want to make my registration process more secure where the system will accepts only new usernames. Below shows the code that I have used for the signup.php. Please help me.

And do you think is this code secure enough for SQL injection? If not, which codes can be secure and how?

```
<?php       
include"connection.php";          

    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) //if the user clicks the submit button then the PHP code POST the details 
{
    $user_name = $_POST['username']; 
    $user_password = $_POST['password']; 
    $user_email = $_POST['email']; 

    if($user_name && $user_password && $user_email)
        {
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, type) 
            VALUES ('$user_name', '$user_password', '$user_email', '0')");
            mysql_query($query); 
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("You have been registered");</script>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("All fields required");</script>'; 
       header("location:user_create.html");
    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should change following:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) //if the user clicks the submit button then the PHP code POST the details 
{
    $user_name = $_POST['username']; 
    $user_password = $_POST['password']; 
    $user_email = $_POST['email'];
    // ...
}
```

To this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) //if the user clicks the submit button then the PHP code POST the details 
{
    $user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
    $user_password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
    $user_email = mysql_real_escape_string(($_POST['email']);
    // ...
}
```

Then before you run the `mysql_query($query);` you should check the existence of the user by querying in the database using `select` statement, for example:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='%s' OR username='%s'", $user_email, $user_name);
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result) {
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, type) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%d')", $user_name, $user_password, $user_email, 0));
    mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        // inserted
    }
    else {
        // not inserted
    }
}
```

> MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
> the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension
> should be used.

Comment: I get this error saying Undefined variable: user_email in

Comment: Didn't you declare `$user_email = mysql_real_escape_string(($_POST['email']);` ?

Comment: I did and I tired to take out the bracket that are between post command and $query = sprintf..... command to make it a one method. When i do it, i do not get errors but the code doesnt work. Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent SQL Injection, you must pre-process all variables ( SESSION, COOKIE, GET, POST, and address bar (aka $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .

For this method, PHP has a command called filter_vars, and filter_var .

Most people will use strip_slashes, or mysql_escape_string or mysql_real_escape_string .  While those do serve their purpose, I would recommend running those AFTER filter_vars, and to be extra safe, if you know the data type, check for it.

DO NOT USE preg_match() as this can execute code that is in the $haystack parameter.

```
$filterd = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);
if($filtered) {
    $filtered = sprintf("%s", mysql_real_escape_string($filtered));
    // Now it should be safe to use preg_replace()
    
} else {
    echo 'Username is invalid';
    exit(0);
}

// Your database code here
```

It is also good practice if you know the type of the data being passed to follow up with a check such as

```
is_int($filtered);
```

And even further validation by limiting the input, such as if you are looking for a number in a range, you would do something like this ::

```
$filterd = filter_var($_POST['fieldnumber'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);
if($filtered && is_numeric($filtered)) {
    $filtered = sprintf("%d", mysql_real_escape_string($filtered));
    
    $filtered = intval($filtered);
    
    // Constrain the integer value to a number between 0 and 255
    $filtered = max(255, min(0, $adjust));
    
    // Now it should be safe to use preg_replace()

    
    
} else {
    echo 'Username is invalid';
    exit(0);
}

// Your database code here
```

PHP is an amazing language, as it allows you to do many things in different methods. As such, there is another method which is a filter_var wrapper called filter_input .

There is plenty of documentation and usage examples on php.net's official site at this link
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Briefly explained, it allows you to pass another parameter to specify the input type you wish to filter ( SESSION, COOKIE, GET, POST, etc ),  and is arguably a bit safer than just using **filter_var**

Here is my proposed complete solution which incorporates filters, and prepared statements using the mysqli connection.  Prepared statements eliminate the need to do any escaping on the data as that is handled automatically. There are other checks that are done as well which help protect you from SQL Injection.

```
// Define database connection details
define('MYSQL_SERVER',      'localhost');
define('MYSQL_USER',        'root');
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD',    '');
define('MYSQL_DATABASE',    'test');

// Define SQL query strings
define('SQL_USERCHECK',     "SELECT email,username FROM users WHERE email=? OR username=?");
define('SQL_USERINSERT',    "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Sanitize Variables from POST
    $username   = filter_input(INPUT_POST,  'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);
    $password   = filter_input(INPUT_POST,  'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);
    $email      = filter_input(INPUT_POST,  'email',    FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    $user_added = false;

    // Check if username, password, and email exist after sanitization.
    if($username && $password && $email) {
    
        // Call custom function below for inserting
        if(insert_user($username, $password, $email)) {
            $user_added = true;
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("You have been registered");</script>';
        }
    
    }

    // If user was not added it means that the user exists,
    // or the values for username,password,email were not valid
    // after filtering.
    if(!$user_added) {
        // Added the redirect to Javascript for you.
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("All fields are required"); window.location.replace(\'user_create.html\')</script>';     
    }
}

function insert_user($username, $password, $email) {
    $user_found = false;
    $user_inserted = false;

    $errors = 0;
    
    $cn = new mysqli(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE);
    
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit(0);
    }

    // Prepare the Username || Email check
    if ($s = $mysqli->prepare(SQL_USERCHECK)) {
    
        if(
            // Bind paramaters
            $s->bind_param("s", $username) &&
            $s->bind_param("s", $email)
        ) {
            $s->execute();
            if($row = $stmt->fetch_row()) {
                    // User exists;
                    $user_found = true;
            }
        } else {
            // One of the params did not bind
            $errors++;
        }
        $s->close();
    }

    // If user not found, Insert record
    if(!$user_found && $errors == 0) {
        $type = 0; // You have  "type='0'"  in your SQL insert statement
        if ($s = $mysqli->prepare(SQL_USERINSERT)) {
        
            if(
                // Bind paramaters
                $s->bind_param("s", $username) &&
                $s->bind_param("s", $password) &&
                $s->bind_param("s", $email) &&
                $s->bind_param("i", $type)
            ) {
                $s->execute();
                if($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
                    // User was added to the database
                    $user_inserted = true;
                }
            } else {
                // One of the params did not bind
                $errors++;
            }
            $s->close();
        }
    }
    
    $cn->close();
    return $user_inserted;
    
}
```

Comment: For the SQL insert portion, look at the bottom of 'Sheikh Heera''s answer.  My answer above only addresses your SQL Injection issue thoroughly.

Comment: I have added a code example that resolves both of your questions and uses current database connection standards.  Everything needed for the check is included, and should work as a drop-in replacement for the code you posted (aside from editing the connection details that are defined).

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope the code works. I will try it